# How to bind jsonresult to label text in mvc using javascript

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, jsonresult

I'm trying to bind jsonresult data to label text which are from database but it won't work..
I have posted script code herewith it will get dropdownlist selected value and pass to actionresult and then result data pass as jsonresult

```
<script>
        function getOutletDetails() {
            debugger;
            var centreName = $("#ddl_Outlet").find("option:selected").text();

            $.ajax
                ({
                    url: "@Url.Action("OutletDetails", "AddTickets", new {area="Common"})",
                    type: 'POST',
                    datatype: 'application/json',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ centreName: +centreName }),
                    success: function (result) {

                        $("#lblTelephone1").text(result.Telephone_01);                     

                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Whooaaa! Something went wrong..")
                    },
                });
        }

    </script>
```

Controller Code

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult OutletDetails(string centreName)
        {

            List<tbl_Centre> lstcity = new List<tbl_Centre>();
          //  int id1 = Convert.ToInt32(id);
            //ViewBag.Id = id;
            lstcity = (objbs.CentreBs.GetAll().Where(x => x.CentreName == centreName)).ToList<tbl_Centre>();

            var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstcity, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings() { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });


            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Comment: Jsonresult is not binding to label

Comment: could you provide your html and json results here ?

Comment: yes this is the html

Comment: <label id="lblTelephone1 ">Telephone</label>

Comment: Controller Code

Comment: please update the question with all these code

Comment: Make sure that `result.Telephone_01` is not empty

Comment: yes telephone_01 has a value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187991/discussion-between-vasu-kuncham-and-dasun).

Answer (score 0):

Usually `.text()` will work like this

```js
$('#sampleButton').click(function(){
   $('#SampleId').text($('.userInput').val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label id="SampleId">Sample text</label><br><br>

<input class="userInput" style="width: 300px" type="text" value="new value that will be replace at label"><br><br>

<button id="sampleButton">change label text</button>
```